# Sequelize ClassMethods

Tags: controller, sequelize.js

I am trying to build a simple api for a deposit and withdrawal with a bank account using sequelize and nodejs ,but I am little confused how I use my methods that I put in the classmethods. Can anyone please show how can i use this into my controllers. below is my model

```
  'use strict';
  module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Account = sequelize.define('Account', {
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      balance: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
      pin: DataTypes.INTEGER,

  }, {
      classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
      // associations can be defined here
    },

   addMoney: function(amount){

       amount = Math.abs(amount);

       return this.increment('balance', {by : amount}).save();


   },

   withdrawMoney: function(amount){

           amount = Math.abs(amount);

       return this.decrement('balance', {by : amount}).save();

         }


       }



       });
        return Account;
       }
```

Below is my controllers, but i am not sure how to use my class methods in the controllers

```
     var models = require('../models/index');

    module.exports = {

     newAccount(req, res, next){

        models.Account.create({
          balance: req.body.balance,
          note: req.body.note,
          pin: req.body.pin,





      }).then(function(account){

          res.json(account);

      }).catch(function(error){

          res.json(error)
      })
 },

   listAccount(req, res, next){

     models.Account.
                 findAll({

                 })
                .then(function(accounts) {
                        res.status(200).send(accounts);
                    }).catch(function(error){

                        res.status(400).send(error)
                    });

       }
  }
```

and this is my routes in case, this is just the routes to avoid posting too much code

```
app.get('/accounts', accountCtrl.listAccount);
app.post('/account/new', accountCtrl.newAccount);
app.put('/account/:id', accountCtrl.updateAccount);
app.delete('/account/:id', accountCtrl.removeAccount);
```

Thank you in avdance for any help, I am new to sequelize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking of instance methods. The `this` in instance methods would be an account.

With `classMethods` the `this` is the class its self. Class methods are useful when you need to define custom functionality about many instances.

In your example, perhaps you want to run a function once a month and charge savings accounts below a certain amount a fee (something that my bank does!)

```
classMethods: {
  async findAndCharge(n) {
    const accounts = await this.findAll({ where: { balance: { $lte: n } } });

    for (const account of accounts) {
      await account.charge()
    }
  }
 }
```

This is a somewhat contrived example, but as you can see the `this` in the class method is `Account` (with a cap) not an `account` lower case.

In other contexts this is sometimes a static method.

In your case you should switch to `instanceMethods`.